# Compare one image with Cloudinary storage

Tags: python, opencv, cloudinary

I want to compare one file to a full path of photo's within a Cloudinary path, but I have no actual clue on how to do it. can someone help me?

This is the code I use to do it for a local path

```py
import cv2
import os
import cloudinary

directory = './images'
upload = cv2.imread("images/img1.jpg")

for entry in os.listdir(directory):

    if entry.lower().endswith( ('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif') ):

        fullname = os.path.join(directory, entry)
        print('fullname:', fullname)
        duplicate = cv2.imread(fullname)

        if upload.shape == duplicate.shape:
            print("The images have same size and channels")

            #difference = cv2.subtract(upload, duplicate)
            #b, g, r = cv2.split(difference) 
            #if cv2.countNonZero(b) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(g) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(r) == 0:
            if (upload == duplicate).all():
                print("images are the same")

        else:
            print("images are different")
```

Comment: You will have to read an image from an http link in this case. `import urllib.request as req url = 'your-url-to-image-file'
req.urlretrieve(url, "filename.jpg") img = cv2.imread('filename.jpg')`

Comment: Does this also work for mutiple files in one Cloudinary storage?

Comment: loop through the all files in the folder inside cloudinary storage then it will.

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: you mean res.cloudinairy.com/cloudname/ ?

Comment: But, do I have to do the loop through all the files manually? I had in mind to just make a for loop like (rough example): for every images in (path to images)

Comment: So, probably make an array of all the links of the files within the folder...?

Comment: No need for that there is a way to fetch images link. I am trying.

Comment: How you want to do comparison?

Comment: Just how its done in the code I showed above

Comment: I just added the code to do the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197123/discussion-between-anubhav-singh-and-branco).

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to compare a given image with images present inside a folder on cloudinary storage. I am comparing two images as per the logic described in above code.

```
import urllib.request as req 
import cloudinary            # pip install cloudinary

cloudinary.config(
  cloud_name = 'YOUR-CLOUD-NAME',  
  api_key = 'YOUR-CLOUDINARY-API-KEY',  
  api_secret = 'YOUR-CLOUDINARY-API-SECRET-KEY'  
)

# image you want to compare with images present in cloudinary storage folder
image = cv2.imread('sample_image.jpg')
print(image.shape)

for i in cloudinary.Search().expression("folder:your_folder_name").execute()['resources']:
    img_url = cloudinary.CloudinaryImage(i['url']).build_url()
    # sample-url: http://res.cloudinary.com/duutxbavx/image/upload/v1564333096/test/flower3_zj6hqi.jpg

    img_ext = img_url.split('/')[8].split('.')[1]
    req.urlretrieve(img_url, "filename"+img_ext) 

    img = cv2.imread('filename'+img_ext)
    print(img_url,'\n',(img_ext, img.shape))

    if image.shape == img.shape:
        print("The images have same size and channels")

        if (image == img).all():
                print("images are the same")
    else:
        print("images are different")
```

Sample Cloudinary folder structure:

[image]

Output:

```
(243, 208, 3)
http://res.cloudinary.com/duutxbavx/image/upload/v1564333097/test/flower1_kosjtw.jpg 
 ('jpg', (275, 183, 3))
images are different
http://res.cloudinary.com/duutxbavx/image/upload/v1564333097/test/flower4_kvbehv.jpg 
 ('jpg', (258, 195, 3))
images are different
http://res.cloudinary.com/duutxbavx/image/upload/v1564333096/test/flower2_nmrkfq.jpg 
 ('jpg', (183, 275, 3))
images are different
http://res.cloudinary.com/duutxbavx/image/upload/v1564333096/test/flower3_zj6hqi.jpg 
 ('jpg', (185, 272, 3))
images are different
```

Comment: Yeah sure. Welcome.

Comment: Can you use the `image = cv2.imread('sample_image.jpg')` also for a local file? because it doesn't seem to work for me..?

Comment: It's a normal way of reading an image. Why isn't it working? What is the error?

Comment: Check if path to the image is correct. Otherwise, you will get None.

Comment: I fixed the error, it's the path. But I only get (870, 700, 3) its not telling me if it is the same or not neither the url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197124/discussion-between-anubhav-singh-and-branco).

Comment: Are you getting the result? Actually, it's working for me.